# Why doesn't aryB.forEach(aryA.push.bind(aryA)) work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bind

For example:

```
> var aryA = [];
undefined
> var aryB = [1, 2, 3];
undefined    
> aryB.forEach(aryA.push.bind(aryA));
undefined
> aryA
[1, 0, Array[3], 2, 1, Array[3], 3, 2, Array[3]]
```

Yes, I want to copy the elements from `aryB` to `aryA`. Of course I have other solutions, but why doesn't this method work?
Please forgive if this is a duplicate question. I am a Stackoverflow newcomer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it does "work". `.forEach` passes three arguments to the callback:

1. the current array element
2. the index of the current array element
3. the array itself (i.e. that `.forEach` was called upon)

Since you are passing `push` as callback, you are essentially performing the following call in each iteration:

```
aryA.push(aryB[i], i, aryB);
```

i.e. adding three values to the array, which is exactly what you are seeing as the result:

```
[1, 0, Array[3], 2, 1, Array[3], 3, 2, Array[3]]
 ^  ^  ^         ^  ^  ^
 |  | array      |  |  array
 | 1. index      | 2. index      ...
1. element      2. element
```

---

I guess you just want to push the first argument, in which case you have to pass a function calls `.push` with only the first argument.